# Truffle Fails on Start After Install

Tags: node.js, npm, truffle

I installed Truffle just fine, but I can't call it without getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:98908
function VM (opts = {}) {
              ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =
  at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
  at Module._compile (module.js:374:25)
  at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
  at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
  at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:442:10)
  at startup (node.js:136:18)
  at node.js:966:3
```

System Spec:
uname -a

Linux 7ed9621f5250 4.1.12-103.7.1.el7uek.x86_64

NodeJS v4.2.6

npm v3.5.2

Install commands used:

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install curl nodejs npm
ln -s /usr/bin/nodejs /usr/bin/node
npm install -g truffle
```

I can't find any docs or posts on this in order to troubleshoot. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Node.js 4 doesn't have default values for function parameters. Use a more recent version

Comment: Ok, that did the trick. Thanks! Can you post it as answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also stuck in this. I followed this which work for me, hope it also works for you.
**Remove node and npm completely. Install fresh node and npm using :**

1. wget https://nodejs.org/dist/v8.8.0/node-v8.8.0-linux-x64.tar.gz
2. sudo tar -xf node-v8.8.0-linux-x64.tar.gz --directory /usr/local --strip-components 1
3. node --version
4. npm --version
5. sudo npm install -g truffle
6. mkdir truffle-proj
7. cd truffle-proj
8. truffle init